# Machine learning algorithm to find cloud service provider using similar domain names or url

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cloud

I am currently working on a module which required me to classify certain url's or domain names under their cloud service providers.
For example:
-videos.google.comm, google.videos.com 
 belong to the same cloud service provider google
-http://xsnf.artworx.no,http://xssf2.artworx.no,http://xssf.artworx.no
 belong to the same cloud service provider artworx

Can any one provide me with any information as to whethere there is any machine learning library available to do the above task?

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail? What language are you working in? Do you have a supervised dataset or unsupervised?

Comment: I have certain log files which have domains Unsupervised dataset

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing a whois on the IP Blocks that the DNS resolves to and building a dataset of block allocation strings used by major cloud providers.

example:  whois -h whois.arin.net 24.24.24.24

ripe.net for example does european allocations and apnic asia.